# reproducible encrypted file

Tags: encryption, openssl, zip, gnupg, 7zip

I need to create encryped reproducible file (same command with same password shall produce same encrypted file). I use the command:

`openssl enc -e -aes256 -pbkdf2 -base64 -nosalt -pass "pass:a_key" -out file.tar.gz.enc -in file.tar.gz`

It is ok with reproducing. But seems there is no backward compatibility. The file encrypted with openssl in my Fedora 30 does not decryped in Fedora 23.

It suits me to use another tool (zip, 7z, gpg) to reach my goal, but I need help with "reproduction" options if any.

Comment: You must use an IV or your AES256 is not secure.

Comment: Yes, I know about iv and -salt flag. I use randomly generated very-very-long passwords ("a_key" is just the simplification for the example) and for me possibility to reproduce result of encryption with the password is important. Openssl with -nosalt and my long password is ok, except the tool's lost backward compatibility.

Comment: Have you tried libressl?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

remove -pbkdf2, ignore warning, add -md md5.

Archive created in Fedora 30 successfully unpacked in Fedora 20.